# How to use non class file and call Actions magento1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I want to use webhook 3rd party after receiving (catch a response) in magento 1.9 my code I want to use like this calling at the end a function in **IndexController.php**
My file is **Webhook.php** ubicate at **Helper** folder.

```
require_once ("D:/wamp/www/magento1.9/app/code/local/Ns/Thorleif/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php");

            $input = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $obj = json_decode($input);
            echo 'test1';

            switch ($obj->event) {
                case 'onProductCreated':
                echo 'test2';
                foreach ($obj->payload->SellerSkus as $sku) {
                    echo 'test3';
                    $prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('sku',$sku);
                    $skus = $prod->getData('sku');
                    $img = $prod->getData('image');
                    $websites = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('is_default', 1);
                    $website = $websites->getFirstItem();
                    $websiteId = $website->getId();
                    $websiteCode = $website->getCode();
                    $url = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('web/unsecure/base_url', 'website', $websiteCode);
                    $url .= 'media/catalog/product'.$img;
                    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><Request><ProductImage>';
                    $xml .= '<SellerSkus>';
                    $xml .= '<Images><Image>';
                    $xml .= 
                    $url;
                    $xml .= '</Images></ProductImage></Request>';
                    echo $xml;
                    var_dump(Ns_Thorleif_Adminhtml_IndexController::postImage($xml));

                }

            }
```

But I receive this kind of issues

```
Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action' not found in D:\wamp\www\magento1.9\app\code\local\Ns\Thorleif\controllers\Adminhtml\IndexController.php</b> on line 2
```

Or if I put it like class file I have a "expecting function" error or "Mage" class doesn't find at level "Mage::getModel".
How Can I post at the end **postImage($xml)** called from controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the numerous best practices you're ignoring, this should be possible when you add:

`require_once '/path/to/magento/app/Mage.php';`

in the top of your file.

After that, do a: `Mage::app('admin');` to initialize Magento.

Afterwards, you should be able to use Magento and include the controller Class.